# Should I inflate tires that are low pressure from freezing weather?

Tags: tires

The PSI inevitably drops in tires during cold weather. Today, I'm getting a low pressure warning because of the freezing temperatures.

Should I inflate them while it's still freezing? If so, how much? If not, why not?

Usually they warm up on their own during driving, but on short in town  trips they don't get warm enough to turn off the alert. (They go from 24 to 25, should be 32 PSI).

Comment: Not  below the freezing point. Moisture in the air will freeze the valve open and you will have a flat tire in the morning.

Answer (score 5):

While the tires are cold, raise the pressure up to the amount which should be in them. If that pressure (what's on the door tag in most cars) is 32psi, then that's where it should be. When the temperature gets warm out, you'll more than likely need to lower the pressure in them so they'll be back down to the normal pressure. If you have tire pressure sensors, most will not only tell you when low, but will tell you when they are too high as well.